# How to increase request time for kafka consumer

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

I am using Kafka with Spring Listener. Following is piece of code.
In the past we have published more than 100k messages to test topic and system seems to be working fine.
But few days back, I changed the groupId of consumer. After that this new consumer tried to process all the message from start and which takes lot of time. But after sometime may be (10 sec) broker kickoff the consumer.
so result no kafka register to listen message.

```
 @KafkaListener(
            topicPattern = "test",
            groupId = "test",
            id = "test",
            containerFactory = "testKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void consume(@Payload String payload) throws IOException {
    }
```

Kafka Consumer configuration:

```
Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true");
    props.put("security.protocol", "SSL");
```

Then I used cli to read message with following command and observed same behavior. After exactly 10 sec consumer stop reading message from kafka.

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test
```

How to increase request time out for kafka client or some other better approach to solution this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
In the past we have published more than 1 lac message to test topic and system seems to be working fine.
```

Does your Kafka has the required data? Kafka does **not** store messages forever. The duration of messages is governed by the retention set in the broker/s. If your data is older than the retention period, it will be lost.

Comment: I am mean we customized our retention policy to store data and past mean just few days back. But here point is not data availability. its about processing time by consumer.

Comment: assuming that you used the from beginning flag in the console consumer, it will print through all the messages. It won't time out by itself. That is why my first guess was it simply read through all the data (which was much less than your expectation)